# Ajax clear results before new request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax code that return data from API based on selected option in dropdown, the problem is when I change dropdown option it will not clear old data and just add new data to previous ones in my append.

## Logic

1. Select option from dropdown 1 `postchoose`
2. Append result in dropdown 2 `postdets`
3. Change option in dropdown 1 `postchoose`
4. Clear options in dropdown 2 `postdets`
5. Append new data to dropdown 2 `postdets`

[image: one]

## Code

```
$('body').on('change', '#postchoose', function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
    });
    var cityID = $("#city option:selected").val();
    var weight = ["{{$totalWeight}}"];
    var courierName = $(this).val();
    if(courierName) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('rajaajax') }}/'+weight+'/'+cityID+'/'+encodeURI(courierName),
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function(data) {
            // append data
            $('select[name="postdets"]').append('<option>test</option');
          }
        });
    } else {
      $('select[name="postdets"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Pilih</option>");
    }
});
```

## Question

How to clear my append part `success:function(data) {` when `courierName` is changed before new data appends?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, or which field is which. Please edit your question to make it more clear, preferably by including your HTML. In any case, the code that runs when the API returns data is `success:function(data) {`, so that's where you should do the processing.

Comment: @kmoser I've added logic to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

As I wanted it clear out second dropdown as soon as option is changed in first dropdown. Here is what I did:

```
$('body').on('change', '#postchoose', function(e){
  $('select[name="postdets"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Processing...</option>");
  //other lines....
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{ url('rajaajax') }}/'+weight+'/'+cityID+'/'+encodeURI(courierName),
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data) {
      $('select[name="postdets"]').empty().append("<option value='' selected>Select</option>");
      //rest of it...
    }
  });
});
```

Now when I change option of first dropdown it shows `processing...` and when data is ready it says `select`.

[image: one]

[image: two]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you did not clear `$('select[name="postdets"]')` before appending a new option. You can try add `$('select[name="postdets"]').empty()` immediately after success function.

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  success: function(data) {
    $('select[name="postdets"]').empty();
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks I have had to improve your answer to match with my logic but i voted up your answer.